# Ionic - service data loss during page refresh

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have created a AuthService, which consist of a login method that set the value of the current user:

```
public static currentUser: User;

    constructor() { }

    login(name: string, psw: string): Promise<boolean> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (name == "admin" && psw == "admin") {
                AuthService.currentUser =
                    {
                        name: name,
                        role: 0,
                        id: null
                    }
                resolve(true);
            }
            else if (name == "user" && psw == "user") {
                AuthService.currentUser =
                    {
                        name: name,
                        role: 1,
                        id: '123'
                    }
                resolve(true);
            }
            else {
                reject(false);
            }
        });
    }
```

In the login page ts:

```
     this.auth.login(this.user.name, this.user.psw).then(async success => {
          if (success) {
            this.navctr.navigateForward("/menu")
          }
    })
```

Finally in the menu page:

```
console.log(AuthService.currentUser)
```

The value of the currentuser is there but whenever i refresh the page, the currentuser's value became undefined

EDIT:
I have solved the problem by storing the value using ionic's built-in local storage function during user login success,

```
localStorage.setItem("userName", AuthService.currentUser.name)
localStorage.getItem("userName")
```

Comment: What do you mean by refresh the page? If you reload the browser then it will be forgotten unless you save the state somewhere persistent. Or do you mean navigating to a different page by clicking a link within the app?

Comment: yes the data is loss when the browser is reloaded, the value of currentUser is still there when i am navigating around the app. How exactly should i store the state of the value, I thought that having the service to hold the variable is sufficient.

Comment: I've posted an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a extra component for the login-values,
see example:

```
export var global = {
    loginState : false
};
```

Component:

```
import {global} from "./global";

loginSubmit()
{
    var email = this.loginForm.value.email.trim();
    var password = this.loginForm.value.password.trim();

    this.userService.submitLogin(email, password)
        .subscribe((response) => {
            if(response.result == 1) 
            {
                global.loginState = true;
                this.menu.close();
            }
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });

}
```

In case that you lose data because of a complete reload of the component it is a good practise to use a @input()-value to get the reference to the data from a root-component which remains in memory. Here is a example:

```
@Component({
 selector: 'hero-detail',
 templateUrl: './hero-detail.component.html'
})
export class DataDetailComponent {
 @Input() data: Data;
}
```

The root-component can do the load and save to localStorage or sqlite-database for example.

Comment: Its not working, I added the component and when the user login, I set `global.loginState = true; ` when user login succeed, then its fine but still when the page is being reloaded, the value become false again

Answer (score 0):

### Single Page App Concepts

When the page is reloaded everything is lost.

The app can remember things as you navigate around the "pages" of the app because what you are really doing is loading in different bits of html to the same page.

If you navigate away from the app or reload the browser page then the JavaScript is wiped and it starts again.

### Data Storage

The solution for this is to use a persistent storage mechanism.

The most common one is storing data in a cookie.

You can also use the various database technologies available. There are many different ones and the best one depends on the mobile platform and which browser you are using. To solve this Ionic have invented Ionic Storage. This gives a single common interface to all of the different technologies. You just tell it to save the data and it picks the best storage mechanism available. You can read more about Ionic Storage here:

- [Data Storage - Ionic Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/storage)

(Actually, I just posted this, and then noticed your update where you have discovered localStorage. This is one of the technologies that Ionic Storage wraps around. You should use Ionic Storage over local storage for better cross device/platform compatibility)

### Security

Another important consideration to keep in mind is security. Rolling your own authentication mechanism is not something that is suggested. Hackers are super smart and can use so many things against you that you will likely create security problems for yourself by trying to write your own login library.

For example, on the simple end of things, make sure you don't save the actual password in to the cookie or storage mechanism as it's not secure.

On the more complicated end there are things like timing attacks, which means that even just responding to the password being wrong can make your site hackable. Checking the username is wrong is quicker to reply to than calculating the hash of the password so people can use it to figure things out.

You also should never say if its the username or password that is wrong, just stay vague,  because then the hackers can use it to figure out which emails/usernames are valid accounts.

If this is just an experiment to get some hands on experience with the moving parts of Ionic then that's fine but if you plan to roll this out to users you should seriously consider a 3rd party solution.